# How do I normalize a string?

Tags: .net, string, unicode, windows-store-apps, unicode-normalization

In .NET you can normalize (NFC, NFD, NFKC, NFKD) strings with [`String.Normalize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx) and there is a  [`Text.NormalizationForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.normalizationform.aspx) enum.

In .NET for Windows Store Apps, both are not available. I have looked in the `String` class and in the `System.Text` and `System.Globalization` namespaces, but found nothing.

Have I missed something? How do I normalize strings in Windows Store Apps?

Does anyone have an idea why the `Normalize` method was not made available for Store Apps?

Comment: `String.Normalize` relies on native functions built in normaliz.dll. I dug a bit and found that it uses [NormalizeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319093(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Since it is specific to Windows it is not available for Windows Store Apps. Unfortunatelly, I have no knowledge about alternatives.

Comment: @AlexanderManekovskiy You are wrong, [`NormalizeString` is on the approved list of Win32 and COM API functions usable in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452772).

Comment: @casperOne Wow, where was my eyes?! Thank you for pointing on this list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've pointed out, the [`Normalize` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.normalize.aspx) is not available on the [`String` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) on Windows store apps.

However, this just calls the [`NormalizeString` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319093) in the Windows API.

Even better, this function is in [the approved list of Win32 and COM API functions usable in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452772).

That said, you'd make the following declarations:

```
public enum NORM_FORM 
{ 
  NormalizationOther  = 0,
  NormalizationC      = 0x1,
  NormalizationD      = 0x2,
  NormalizationKC     = 0x5,
  NormalizationKD     = 0x6
};

[DllImport("Normaliz.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
    SetLastError = true)
public static extern int NormalizeString(NORM_FORM NormForm,
    string lpSrcString,
    int cwSrcLength,
    StringBuilder lpDstString,
    int cwDstLength);
```

You'd then call it like so:

```
// The form.
NORM_FORM form = ...;

// String to normalize.
string unnormalized = "...";

// Get the buffer required.
int bufferSize = 
    NormalizeString(form, unnormalized, unnormalized.Length, null, 0);

// Allocate the buffer.
var buffer = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);

// Normalize.
NormalizeString(form, unnormalized, unnormalized.Length, buffer, buffer.Length);

// Check for and act on errors if you want.
int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

Comment: Is `StringBuffer lpDstString` correct, or did you mean `StringBuilder`?

Comment: I am trying to get it work (using `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, which AFAIK does not exist), but it does not work. `buffer`is always "empty" (contains nothing but a bunch of `\0`). Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus `StringBuffer` was an error, it's supposed to be `StringBuilder`.  Are you checking the return value from `NormalizeString` and the `Marhsal.GetLastWin32Error` values?  They will give you more insight if something is going wrong.

Comment: Hello for me buffer.Length is zero as it has not been filled yet which is why it results in an empty buffer!!!! Also, when I run NormalizeString with null, 0 for the final parameters and get the expected size as per the documentation, it is returning 64 for a 6 character English string!!!!!!!! This is not right!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is my working code, I don't need to trim the string termination characters as there is none present but I am doing so just in case.

By using -1 instead of a specified length I am letting it auto find the string terminator and this is the only way I could get it to work properly in a WinRT/WinPhoneRT platform target

```
       int bufferSize = NormalizeString(Globals.NORM_FORM.NormalizationKD, toNormalise, -1, null, 0);

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);

        // Normalize.
        NormalizeString(Globals.NORM_FORM.NormalizationKD, toNormalise, -1, buffer, buffer.Capacity);

        // Check for and act on errors if you want.
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if(error !=0)
        {
            throw (new Exception("A Win32 error with code " + error + " has occured in unmanaged NormalizeString"));
        }
        char[] trim = {'\0'};

        return buffer.ToString().TrimEnd(trim);
```