# Characters adding in array in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make a simple love calculator. I have pre-defined all the values of characters like a = 1, b=2 and all. But the thing is I don't know how to count length and add all characters one by one.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question doesn't meet the site standard of quality, and, as your question is worded, it seems you need to get the basics of programming with a full course or tutorials. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is so little love in this sad world... a = 1, b = 2 and z = 26 or you have another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of what you could do, if a = 1, b = 2, ... , z = 26

```
string name = "Amélie Benoît Françoise Ågot Annbjørg";

// We transform letters with diacritics to "pure" letters (é->e, ç ->c...)
string normalized = name.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
var onlyLetters = normalized.Where(x => x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z' || x >= 'a' && x <= 'z');

// Note that the ø of Annbjørg will be stripped :-(
string strippedName = new string(onlyLetters.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("Calculating for {0}", strippedName);

int sum = 0;

foreach (char ch in onlyLetters)
{
    char ch2 = char.ToUpper(ch);

    // char have a value... 'A' == 65, 'B' == 66 and so on,
    sum += ch2 - 'A' + 1;
}

// Done
```

Note that this code will work in an unfunny way in Turky, because they have [4 i](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) :-) There are even problems with Norwegian names that have the ø, without speaking of names that don't use the "european" alphabet :-)

Full example: http://ideone.com/ZHHU4G

You can replace the Normalize method call by using this method (that should be compatible with Windows Store):

```
public enum NORM_FORM
{
    NormalizationOther = 0,
    NormalizationC = 0x1,
    NormalizationD = 0x2,
    NormalizationKC = 0x5,
    NormalizationKD = 0x6
};

[DllImport("Normaliz.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int NormalizeString(NORM_FORM NormForm,
    string lpSrcString,
    int cwSrcLength,
    StringBuilder lpDstString,
    int cwDstLength);

public static string NormalizeString(string unnormalized, NORM_FORM form)
{
    if (unnormalized == string.Empty)
    {
        return unnormalized;
    }

    int bufferSize = NormalizeString(form, unnormalized, unnormalized.Length, null, 0);

    if (bufferSize <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Win32 error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);

    int result = NormalizeString(form, unnormalized, unnormalized.Length, sb, bufferSize);

    if (result <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Win32 error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and

```
string normalized = NormalizeString(name, NORM_FORM.NormalizationD);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate me this line:    //sum += ch2 - 'A' + 1;

Comment: @TijAnManandhar Let's say the name is BERNADETTE. Let's begin with B. ch2 == 'B'. 'B' - 'A' == 1, because 'B' == 66 ('B' has unicode value 66), 'A' == 65 ('A' has unicode value 65), 66 - 65 == 1. And then we add 1, like 1 + 1 == 2, because you have that 'A' should be 1. Now take the E. ch2 == 'E'. 'E' - 'A' == 4, because 'E' == 69, 'A' = 65, 69 - 65 == 4, and 4 + 1 == 5.

Comment: You need `using System.Linq`;

Comment: i cannot use this code

`string normalized = name.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
var onlyLetters = normalized.Where(x => x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z' || x >= 'a' && x <= 'z');`

and when i use this code
`foreach (char ch in onlyLetters)
{
    char ch2 = char.ToUpper(ch);

    // char have a value... 'A' == 65, 'B' == 66 and so on,
    sum += ch2 - 'A' + 1;
}`
the result is always 682. I'm working on for win store

Comment: i still can't use normalize

Comment: @TijAnManandhar Remove the normalization part. Change to `string normalized = name;`. if you want to reintroduce it later, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15257259/613130

Comment: thank you so much. Its finally done :)